# Web transformation files get copied to root + bin

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config-transform

I recently upgrade my project to vs 2010.
One of the main reasons for doing so is the addition of web transformation files.

With my existing project upgraded : i clicked Add Config Transforms, i updated a simple value from my config for testing purposes and i published my project to the file system.


What i expected was to find 1 transformed web.config in my root folder.
What i found was 1 transformed web.config + all my config transformation files as well:
Web.Debug.config , web.Release.config and web.Test.config
Also strange : all these files were outputted to my bin folder as well.
Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? It seems to work fine if i create an entirely new web  project but i want to fix my existing upgraded project.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kind of a dumb cause but the property Copy to output directory affects all of the versions for that web.config. 
Changing it to Do Not copy resolves my issue.

Comment: I had to change it to Do Not Copy and also change Build Action from 'Content' to 'None' and then it stopped copying to the output directory for me.