# Web.Config Transformations just copy the web.*.config Files

Tags: web-config, microsoft-web-deploy, config-transformation

I'm fairly new to this but it seems really simple and i want to know why on earth it is not working.  I have create a bunch of regions configuration manager (test, UAT, dr prod ect.) and  then i have right clicked on my web.config and added config transformation, filled out the relevant files.

Now when i go to Build deployment package for a region and them import it onto another machine it just copies out the web.test.config or whatever files.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Help?!

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing this bastard of a problem, you need to have do not copy on for all of your files and build action = content

[Web transformation files get copied to root + bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065218/web-transformation-files-get-copied-to-root-bin)